# About $\mathbb Z_{p}[\sqrt{k}]$, when is it a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I give up. I'm new in the fields world, and

> I'm trying to give a sufficient and necessary condition for $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[\sqrt{k}]=\{a+b\sqrt{k}:a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_{p}\}$ to be a field ($p$ is a prime and $k$ is a positive integer).

I claim that the condition is that $p$ doesn't divide $k$, but I don't know if this is true, I've tried to prove this but I've got stuck in the "sufficient" part.

It would be great if some of you can help me, thanks!.

Comment: In what universe does this addition make sense?

Comment: Do you mean $\,\Bbb Z_p[x]/(x^2-k)?\ \ $

Comment: Is $\;\Bbb Z_p\;$ for you the prime field of characteristic $\;p\;$ or the $\;p$-adic integers?

Comment: I would assume it would be a prime field of characteristic p.

Comment: Friends, the idea with this set is analogous to: $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[\sqrt{3}]=\{0,1,2,\sqrt{3},1+\sqrt{3},2+\sqrt{3},2\sqrt{3},1+2 \sqrt{3},2+2\sqrt{3}\}$, I saw this problem from Gallian's book, there is not description for this set. I assume the operations are as usual but reducing integer number modulo 3 whenever it can.

Comment: So are you assuming that for example the element $\sqrt{4}$ is not at all related to $2$ as an element of your set? This is what Bill Dubuque also asks about. If this is, indeed, how we are to interpret the set, then here's a hint: In $\Bbb{Z}_7[\sqrt2]$ there are at least for solutions to the equation $x^2=2$, namely $\sqrt2$, $-\sqrt2$, $3$ and $-3$. But in a field a quadratic equation is supposed to have at most two.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I've considered the case of $\sqrt{4}$, and in that case, I guess $\sqrt{4}=2$ is considered an element of $Z_{p}$, and in this case $Z_{p}=Z_{p}[\sqrt{4}]$ Isn't it? Well, in any case, if you guys never heard of this set, I guess that there's something wrong with the statement... I've wrote it here exactly how i've found it. Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: No you got it wrong. The thing you described fits perfectly with the quotient ring Bill gave. And you should learn about quadratic residues :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm new in the world of fields so I don't know anything about quadratic extension or residues. Gallian didn't make any description about that set, I'll wait until i learn those concepts to understand this set adequately. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $F$ is a field, then $F[\sqrt{a}]$ is always a field.

Case I: $a$ is a square in $F$, $b^2 = a$.  Then $F[\sqrt{a}] = F[b] = F$.

Case II: $a$ is not a square in $F$.  Then the polynomial $X^2 - a$ is irreducible, so $F[\sqrt{a}] \cong F[X]/(X^2-a)$ is a field.

More generally, if $R$ is a ring with no zero divisors that contains $F$, and it is finite-dimensional as a vector space over $F$, then it is a field.

The issue raised in the comments is that we might define $F[\sqrt{a}]$ to be $F[X]/(X^2-a)$, rather than the smallest subring of $\overline{F}$ containing $F$ and $\sqrt{a}$ (this appears to be the definition you intend).  But when $a$ is a nonzero square, this is isomorphic to $F\times F$, which is not a field, and when $a=0$, it is isomorphic to $F[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$ (there is a very minor exception when $\operatorname{char}K = 2$, in which case nonzero squares also yield $F[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$).

Comment: @user26857 The original problem assumes that $a$ is a positive integer, which is much stronger.  The question is whether $\sqrt{a}\in F$ or not.

Comment: @user26857 How so?  The definition, as written, is the standard one for adjoining field elements within an algebraic closure.  Even if it is taken to mean the less-standard $F[X]/(X^2-a)$, I answered this as well, in the last paragraph.

Comment: @user26857 Yes, those comments are talking about the same thing I am.  And I really do not see why you would say $k\notin \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @user26857 If you want to provide some specific thing that you think I've said wrong, go ahead.  But I read the comments, twice now, and I have no idea what you're talking about (unless you're confusing $a\in F$ with $\sqrt{a}\in F$, which are very different concerns).

Comment: @user26857 (responding to edit) Again, I don't know why you say $k\notin \mathbb{Z}_p$.  The difference between integers and their residues is mainly irrelevant, in both definitions, and certainly does not affect the answer.

Comment: @user26857 I would have to know what you are claiming before I disagree.  In a literal sense, a positive integer does not lie in $\mathbb{Z}/p$.  However, it is standard to write, e.g. $5\in \mathbb{Z}/p$ to mean $\overline{5}\in \mathbb{Z}/p$.  The distinction is only important in characteristic 2, because of inseparability (which I added a brief note about).